# Problem writing rasters with desired name string

Tags: r, raster

I have a huge number of directories with names such as `"xxxxxxxx2019.01.01"` then I want to pass the desired portion of each directory names to a raster name `"myRas_..."`. However, the raster name changes all of a sudden and this sometimes causes some are overwritten!

Why this is happening? can someone help me to get over this issue please?
Below is a simplified version of my script:

```
library(raster)
set.seed(1234)

#setting working directory
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))

# create data
r <- raster(nrows = 120, ncol = 120, xmn=0)
r[] <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)

dlist <- "xxxxxxxx2019.01.01"

# Write results myRas_...
raster::writeRaster(r,  
                    file.path(getwd(), paste0("myRas_", stringr::str_sub(dlist,-10,-1), collapse = "")), 
                    format = "GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
```

Then the output is surprisingly saved as `myRas_2019.01.tif`, not `myRas_2019_01_01.tif`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably happens because of the dots (.) and can be avoided by replacing dots using `gsub` or something similar. Maybe some else can show you a way to keep the dots.

```
# Write results
raster::writeRaster(r,  
                    file.path(getwd(), paste0("myRas_", gsub("\\.", "_", as.character(stringr::str_sub(dlist,-10,-1))))), 
                    format = "GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
```